# jaxws 4 / java 17: it is not a jaxws or a jaxb binding file

Tags: java, wsdl, maven-plugin, wsimport

I used to generate sources from WSDL/bindings, using jaxws-maven-plugin with spring-boot 2.3.7 and java 11. Now, after upgrading to spring-boot 3.0 and java 17, code generation fails, because my bindings files are ignored with error message

`bindings.xml: not a XML-WS- or XML-B-binding file`

I've seen this error being discussed on StackOverflow, but none with spring-boot 3.0. Here is an example to reproduce error:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
            <xdebug>true</xdebug>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <packageName>com.daimler.daivb.cat.pkimgmt.bl.internal</packageName>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <xdebug>true</xdebug>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

WSDL-File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions name="HelloWorldService"
             targetNamespace="http://example.com/helloworld"
             xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             xmlns:tns="http://example.com/helloworld"
             xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
             xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
             xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

  <types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://example.com/helloworld">
      <xsd:element name="sayHello">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="sayHelloResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="greeting" type="xsd:string"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>

  <message name="sayHelloRequest">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:sayHello"/>
  </message>
  <message name="sayHelloResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:sayHelloResponse"/>
  </message>

  <portType name="HelloWorldPortType">
    <operation name="sayHello">
      <input message="tns:sayHelloRequest"/>
      <output message="tns:sayHelloResponse"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>

  <binding name="HelloWorldBinding" type="tns:HelloWorldPortType">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="sayHello">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>

  <service name="HelloWorldService">
    <port name="HelloWorldPort" binding="tns:HelloWorldBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld"/>
    </port>
  </service>

</definitions>
```

Binding file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:xjc="http://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
               jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"
               jaxb:version="3.0">
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_3_0.xsd">
        <!-- Map xsd:date to java.time.LocalDate -->
        <jaxb:javaType name="java.time.LocalDate"
                       xmlType="xs:date"
                       parseMethod="java.time.LocalDate.parse"
                       printMethod="java.time.LocalDate.toString"/>
        <!-- Map xsd:time to java.time.LocalTime -->
        <jaxb:javaType name="java.time.LocalTime"
                       xmlType="xs:time"
                       parseMethod="java.time.LocalTime.parse"
                       printMethod="java.time.LocalTime.toString"/>
        <!-- Map xsd:dateTime to java.time.LocalDateTime -->
        <jaxb:javaType name="java.time.LocalDateTime"
                       xmlType="xs:dateTime"
                       parseMethod="java.time.LocalDateTime.parse"
                       printMethod="java.time.LocalDateTime.toString"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Any ideas, why this happens? Please give only working answers. I've already tried any hint I could find. I've also tried different plugins (org.codehouse.mojo, com.sun.xml.ws, org.apache.xcf). None of them worked.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I am using with Spring Boot 3.0 and Java 17:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_3_0.xsd"
          version="3.0">
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="service.xsd">
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='OperationOne']">
            <jaxb:javaType name="com.example.api.gen.OperationOne" 
                      parseMethod="valueOf" 
                      printMethod="toString"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='OperationTwo']">
            <jaxb:class name="com.example.api.gen.OperationTwo"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

It differs slightly from your version in the jaxb definition. I am then referencing the binding file (bindings.xml in my case) in the plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <executions>
            <execution>
                    <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
            </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <wsdlDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/</wsdlDirectory>
        <wsdlFiles>
            <wsdlFile>service.wsdl</wsdlFile>
        </wsdlFiles>
        <packageName>com.example.api.gen</packageName>
        <sourceDestDir>${sourcesDir}</sourceDestDir>
        <bindingFiles>
            <bindingFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/bindings.xml</bindingFile>
        </bindingFiles>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

More information about the currently valid schema can be found on the [Jakarta EE](https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb/) homepage.